# How to specify directory where my reference git repos live

Tags: git

Our company has reference git repositories available via NFS for some remote repositories I am cloning using ssh.

Is there a `.gitconfig` setting that will tell git to look here for a reference repo?

The git command I am executing is:

```
git clone ssh://remote-machinename/repos/repo.git --reference ~otheruser/references/repo.git
```

I'd like to automatically add `--reference ~otheruser/references/repo.git` when I type `git clone ssh://remote-machinename/repos/repo.git`, but make it flexible to match other repository names. Is this something I can do with `insteadOf` magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to deplay a git wrapper script which would clone, adding the name of the repo to the reference part, using `--reference-if-able`:

```
git clone ssh://remote-machinename/repos/$1 --reference-if-able ~otheruser/references/$1
```

The idea being, as mentioned in [git clone --reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---reference-if-ableltrepositorygt):

> When using the `--reference-if-able`, **a non existing directory is skipped with a warning instead of aborting the clone**.